# UDPclient.Client.Lingerstate

Tags: c#, .net, udp, arrays

my problem is this, I am sending a series of byte arrays (chunks) of a big array through the `UDPClient`, but after the server calls `UDPClient.Close()` the messages cut off abruptly.
Because of this I am trying to set the lingerstate of the socket.

```
UdpClient dataStream = new UdpClient(_cClient, m_iUDPListenPort);
dataStream.AllowNatTraversal(true);
dataStream.Client.LingerState.Enabled = true;
dataStream.Client.LingerState.LingerTime = 10;
```

This causes a socketException,

```
dataStream.Client.LingerState = new LingerOption(true, 10);
```

and this one also causes a SocketException
how can I set a delay without the `Thread.Sleep()` option?

Comment: it gives me just a SocketException :\